# How to catch only on exception type

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Is there any way to catch only based on exception types, without using an identifier, just like the way Python does. When I tried following, the compiler complains about missing identifier:

```java
try {
    doSthThatThrows();
} catch (IOException) {
    handleIOException();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException) {
    handleArgumentException();
}
```

…reporting this error:

```
Main.java:19: error: <identifier> expected
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException)
                                    ^
1 error
```

Comment: Why not just put an identifier there but not use it?

Comment: No, you cannot do this. You can put a variable there that is not used, but you can't leave it out. It is part of the language syntax, and Java is blessedly fussy about that sort of thing.

Comment: If put an identifer without using it, the code checker would complains about unused varaibles, right?

Comment: @fluter if its mandatory to remove the code checker warnings use @SuppressWarnings("unused").

Comment: @Devendra ok, I see, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In plain Java you must have an identifier for the name and you [*cannot* use an underscore for the name](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-_-underscore-variable-name-java/) (a common way to avoid giving a name/identifier in [Groovy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Groovy)).

See the article by Oracle, [*Catching Multiple Exception Types and Rethrowing Exceptions with Improved Type Checking*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html)

Change your code to name a variable for the exception being thrown. For example, `e` in the code below. Note that you can recycle the same variable name across the `catch` statements.

```
try {
    doSthThatThrows();
} catch ( IOException e ) {
    …
} catch ( IllegalArgumentException e ) {
    …
}
```